# How to type a static function paramater as a table of objects

Tags: object, plsql

I would like to know if there is a way to do this:

I have a type object A. I would like to add a static function in the object A declaration which has a parameter whose type is a table of object A.

How can do that knwo that :

1. I cannot do this :

   STATIC FUNCTION blabla (myList IN TABLE OF A) : the compiler does not understand table here
2. I cannot create type xxx TABLE OF A because A is unknown at the time of the creation of this new type

So to sum up :

```
create or replace 
TYPE myObject AS OBJECT (
    STATIC FUNCTION blabla (myList IN TABLE OF myObject)  
);
```

Comment: Maybe you could use ANYDATA datatype? Your static function would take ANYDATA parameter and then retrieve actual objects. You can read more about it here: [ANYDATA Datatype](http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=218)

Comment: The problem is how to cast after that to TABLE OF myObject

Comment: Check my answer - I have tested the solution and it seems to work as, I think, you expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution using the ANYDATA datatype:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE 
TYPE my_object AS OBJECT (
  some_number NUMBER,
  STATIC FUNCTION static_test_function(p_my_objects_tab IN OUT ANYDATA) RETURN NUMBER
);
/

CREATE TYPE my_object_tab_t AS TABLE OF my_object;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE
TYPE BODY my_object AS
  STATIC FUNCTION static_test_function(p_my_objects_tab IN OUT ANYDATA) RETURN NUMBER
  AS
    v_my_objects_tab my_object_tab_t;
    v_dummy NUMBER;
    v_result NUMBER := 0;
  BEGIN
    -- get the collection from ANYDATA object - v_dummy holds status (succes or not)
    v_dummy := p_my_objects_tab.GetCollection(v_my_objects_tab);

    -- as an example, loop through the list and sum up the some_number field
    FOR v_i IN v_my_objects_tab.FIRST..v_my_objects_tab.LAST
    LOOP
      v_result := v_result + v_my_objects_tab(v_i).some_number;
    END LOOP;

    RETURN v_result;
  END;
END;
/

DECLARE
  v_my_objects_tab my_object_tab_t;
  v_anydata_my_objects_tab ANYDATA;

  v_result NUMBER;
BEGIN
  -- create the collection and populate it with some sample data
  v_my_objects_tab := my_object_tab_t();

  v_my_objects_tab.EXTEND();
  v_my_objects_tab(v_my_objects_tab.LAST()) := my_object(5);

  v_my_objects_tab.EXTEND();
  v_my_objects_tab(v_my_objects_tab.LAST()) := my_object(10);

  -- create ANYDATA object from the collection
  v_anydata_my_objects_tab := ANYDATA.ConvertCollection(v_my_objects_tab);

  -- call the static function expecting ANYDATA parameter
  v_result := my_object.static_test_function(v_anydata_my_objects_tab);

  dbms_output.put_line(v_result);
END;
/
```

Output: `15`